# Creating a library in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, macos

What's the proper file hierarchy for a library in Swift? For example, should I name the main directory `lib` and put all the files in it? And where should I put the tests?

And what's the naming convention for the files: `myFile1.swift` or `my_file.swift` or `MyFile.swift`? There's no information in Google or at the apple's website about this topic.

Comment: You are not finding information about 'libraries' because they are referred to as 'frameworks'.  You start with Xcode, create a project, add a framework target, and set the 'Defines Module' build setting to 'yes'.

Comment: @GoZoner, `add a framework target` - how?

Comment: There is Apple documentation on projects/targets in Xcode.  Have a look as there are lots of options.